# UCanAccess can not find my DB

Tags: java, ms-access-2007, ucanaccess

I'm trying to connect my Java code to a table in access using UCanAccess
here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class HH {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // opens a connection to the database
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/user/Documents/Database5.accdb‬");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    }
}
```

for some reason it throws this:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.0 given file does not exist: C:\Users\user\Documents\Database5.accdb‬
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:258)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at HH.main(HH.java:8)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: given file does not exist: C:\Users\user\Documents\Database5.accdb‬
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:362)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:248)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DefaultJackcessOpener.open(DefaultJackcessOpener.java:35)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.<init>(DBReference.java:160)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReferenceSingleton.loadReference(DBReferenceSingleton.java:51)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:96)
    ... 3 more
```

the path is OK, if I enter it into windows explorer it opens my DB.

Comment: It looks like the user of the java process hasn't the needed rights on the given directory  "C:\Users\user\Documents\". What if you change the accdb position?

Comment: thank you very much !
I tried to move it to other places and after it didn't worked I moved it to the package in eclipse, works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with UCanAccess etc I think your code `"jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/user/Documents/Database5.accdb‬"`

Should be

`"jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Database5.accdb‬"`

**Reason:** in the filesystem it uses the backslash rather than forwards slash, and in java strings the '\' character is an escape, so to enter just one of that character you need to escape itself: `\\` which will appear as `\` to the `getConnection` method

Comment: No, many systems like Java, PHP, etc. accept forward slashes as path separators on Windows systems. "C:/path/to/file.accdb" will work just fine.

Comment: @Gord Thompson still doesn't work for me , it gives the error "given file not found" over and over  any idea to why this is happening ?